# Why i am unable to launch Thymeleaf Template with springboot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am using IntelliJ IDEA community Edition 2020.1.2 x64 and written a program using Spring DataJPA and Thymeleaf,there is no problem with my code and i am not getting error but when i am passing URL which i mapped in controller class i am unable to get desired result i.e the thymeleaf template which i have created is not displayed on browser.

**I am posting the controller class,thymeleaf template and output which i am getting on browser to make you clear:-**

**controller class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ecommerce")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/available")
    public String ShowAllProducts(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("listProducts",productService.getAllProducts());
        return "availableProducts";
    }
}
```

**Thymeleaf template:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="html://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AvailableProducts</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Product List</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>p_id</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <th>Productcost</th>
            <th>QuantityAvailable</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
            <td th:text="${product.productId}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.productName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.productCost}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.quanityAvailable}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output on browser:-**

[image]

**Dependency added:-**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties:-**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommerce
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=deep

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath*:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
```

At last when i am passing url `http://hocalhost:8080/ecommerce/available` what i am seeing in console is,hibernate is accessing the database every time.

Thanks in advance..
Please help i am stuck and don't know what i am doing wrong and not able to figure out on my own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case seems like controller is just returning string "availableProducts" and its not resolving as thymleaf template. you can just return some dummy name("availableProductsTest") and you will see same(availableProductsTest) on the web page.

Did you referred to sample https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Sample code is available here .. git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content.git

if you just add your product class and modify the Greetings contoller like below then you can see its working!

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        List<Products> productList= new ArrayList<>();
        Products product = new Products("productId","ProductName", "ProductCost", "ProductQtyAvlb");
        productList.add(product);
         model.addAttribute("listProducts",productList);
        return "greeting";
    }
```

Also modify greetings template as below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
    <div align="center">
    <h1>Product List</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>p_id</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <th>Productcost</th>
            <th>QuantityAvailable</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
            <td th:text="${product.productId}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.productName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.productCost}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.quanityAvailable}"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Hope this Helps! Happy Coding

Web reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Whenever you get Whitelabel Error Page you will have details about error listed on same page also same details can be seen in server logs or on console of the application.

For example if i use wrong template name in controller then i see below:

[image]
2020-07-28 22:35:51.031 ERROR 19572 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "greeting1": Error resolving template [greeting1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [greeting1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]

Comment: i am fetching data from MySql database if we remove  `productService.getAllProducts()` from` modal.addAttribute()` how it will work..

Comment: Point here is not to remove productService.getAllProducts() but still read from your Database. but in your code it seems like controller is just returning a string rather then a template. And sample code which i shared is a standalone app to see how thymleaf is being returned via controller. Please try to run the sample and see what is different in your code due to which code did not work.

Comment: @Prograammer i am getting whitelabel error page and i have placed html file in template folder instead.

Comment: Whenever you get Whitelabel Error Page you will have details about error listed on same page also same details can be seen in server logs or on console of the application.      For example if i use wrong template name in controller then i see above modified answer: